# the file is not created after adding a try / except block in python

Tags: python, file, date, exception

exactly as in the title, after adding a try / except block the file is not created when deleted everything works, what could be the reason?
the program's task is to create a file with the current time, date, etc., in the exception block, wants to display a message so that the same files will not be created twice.

```
import datetime


def file():

 try:
    filename = datetime.datetime.now()

    with open(filename.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".txt", "w") as file:
        file.write("")
    file()
 except FileExistsError:
    print("file already exists")
```

Comment: `open()` doesn't raise an exception if the file already exists. It just overwrites it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "exclusive" mode to raise an exception if the file already exists.

```
def file():

 try:
    filename = datetime.datetime.now()

    with open(filename.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".txt", "x"):
        pass
 except FileExistsError:
    print("file already exists")

file()
```

There's no need to write anything to the file. Since it didn't already exist, there won't be anything in it, so you don't need to overwrite it.

I also removed the recursive call to `file()`, since it creates infinite recursion. The call to the function should be after it's defined.

Also, don't use the same name for your variable as the function. The recursive call was actually trying to use the opened file as a function.

Comment: Are you calling the function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **os** for check if a file already exists

```
import datetime
import os


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".txt"
        
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            with open(filename, "w") as file:
                file.write("")
                
        else:
            raise FileExistsError
    
    except FileExistsError:
        print("file already exists")
```

Comment: This has [TOCTOU race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)

Comment: Yes, you're right, the best way is to use the "x" mode to access at the file as you mentioned in you answer.